# Functions of bounded pointwise variation in a open set

Tags: real-analysis, functions

In [Leoni's book](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/A_First_Course_in_Sobolev_Spaces.html?id=W3RLWwnY0RkC&redir_esc=y), it is defined when a function $f$ defined in an interval has bounded pointwise variation and, from this, it is defined when a function defined in any open set has bounded pointwise variation in this way:

**Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ a open set and $\{I_n\}$ a countable family of open intervals in a such way that $\Omega = \bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty} I_n$. We say that $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ has bounded pointwise variation if**

$$
Var_\Omega f:= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} Var_{I_n} f < +\infty
$$

where $Var_A f$ denotes the total (pointwise) variation of $f$ in $A$.

My question is: How to show that $Var_\Omega f$ is independent of the choice of the countable family that covers $\Omega$?

Any help is very appreciated.

PS: $Var_I f := \sup \{V(f,P) : P \ \mbox{partition of} \ I\}$ and $V(f,P) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|$ where $P=\{x_0,...,x_k\}$